# How to use PORT command for IPv6 address

Tags: sockets, ftp

From https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/PORT-FTP-command, I can see that the PORT command basically takes input in form of  PORT (h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2). But I need to initiate a PORT command(or some alternative) on an IPv6 machine. Is there any way / alternative so that I may accomplish the connection?

When I tried to run PORT command with IPv6 Address using recv WinAPI
`recv(tsocket, buf, size, flag);`
the output was : 
500 'PORT xxxx,xxxx,xxx,xxxx,xxxx,4,176': command not understood.

4,176 are the port on which I am trying to connect(i.e. 1200), and rest 'x' are the IPv6 address of my system.

I am trying to achieve an Active Mode Connection on FTP.

> Extra : Is there a way that I may establish a connection between IPv4 FTP server and IPv6 client?

Answer (score 3):

For IPv6, you need to use `EPRT` instead of `PORT`.

`EPRT` is defined in [RFC 2428](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2428) (*FTP Extensions for **IPv6** and NATs*), in [section 2: The ERPT Command](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2428#section-2).

The RFC gives this example:

```
EPRT |2|1080::8:800:200C:417A|5282|
```

Of course, the counter party need to support the command. If it does not, you cannot use IPv6.

Comment: Fortunately, if the other party does not support `EPRT` or IPv6, the `EPRT` command will fail with a detectable error code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I may establish a connection between IPv4 FTP server and IPv6 client?

Not directly. You would need to have some gateway which translates between IPv6 and IPv4 at the IP level but also at the application level, i.e. rewrite the addresses used for connection setup and maybe also translate between PORT/PASV (IPv4 only) and EPRT/EPSV (IPv6 and IPv4, but not supported by all IPv4 systems).

Comment: Though, it is possible for the client to connect to the FTP server's control port using IPv4, and then perform file transfers on the data port using IPv6, if the server allows that. `EPRT`/`EPSV` allow that by including `<net-prt>` on a per-data-connection basis.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: correct, but this would still not be a transfer between IPv4 and IPv6. It would only be the control connection using a different IP version than the data connection. But both IP versions would need to be fully supported on both sides for this.